# DLOOKUP STRING CRITERA with simple example

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I need help with retrieving the last names for the Authors on the Chapters table.

First, to start this example you need two tables:

tblAuthors

```
ID  FirstName   LastName
1   Rob         Cooper
2   Geoff       Griffith
3   Teresa      Hennig
4   Jerry       Dennison
```

tblChapters

```
ID  Author
1   Rob
2   Rob
3   Rob
4   Geoff
5   Geoff
6   Teresa
7   Jerry
```

while the tblChapters table is selected open, I click the create query button.

Then I add the fields ID and Author. To the right of Author I start a builder for my DLOOKUP().

My Dlookup uses strings.

It doesn't work.

Can you help me?

```
RetrieveLastName: DLookUp("[LastName]","[tblAuthors]","[FirstName]='" & [Author] & "'")
```

It works when I put for example:

```
RetrieveLastName: DLookUp("[LastName]","[tblAuthors]","[FirstName]='Teresa'")
```

but that is not what I want.

Thanks!

I have looked a multiple multiple websites and tried numbers syntaxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for data like the following (from the table `tblChapters`):

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | Author | LastName |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | Rob    | Cooper   |
|  2 | Rob    | Cooper   |
|  3 | Rob    | Cooper   |
|  4 | Geoff  | Griffith |
|  5 | Geoff  | Griffith |
|  6 | Teresa | Hennig   |
|  7 | Jerry  | Dennison |
+----+--------+----------+
```

I would suggest not using a DLookup in a query setting, this will only cause you headaches.

I would suggest you use this SQL:

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.Author, ta.LastName 
FROM tblChapters tc
INNER JOIN tblAuthors ta ON tc.Author = ta.FirstName
ORDER BY tc.ID
```

If you are **very inclined** to use the `Design View` to setup a query in Access, use the following:

Query Design > Use Tables `tblChapters` and `tblAuthors`, link on `tblChapters.Atuhor` = `tblAuthors.FirstName`

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Field: |     id      |   Author    |  Lastname  |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Table: | tblChapters | tblChapters | tblAuthors |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

**SIDE NOTE**: *This strategy only works in the case where there are no duplicated FirstNames and/or conflicts accross the two tables.*

Comment: I figured it out! There was a problem with the DataType in the tbl.Chapters table. It was Number for Authors, when it should've been text. I knew something was off when I was getting a syntax error '[FirstName]=1'" and that was coming up when I had four """" at the end and two "" after the equals sign for some reason. However, the normal convention works now. I was using an example database, so that is why there was an error, but thank you!